# Send mail to external SMTP server (linux command)

Tags: linux, smtp, sendmail, mailx

Is there anyway to send an email to an external smtp server?
my smtp server is XXX.XXX.XXX.66, listening on port 25

Is there a single command to send an email to this server a on port 25 without any setting up any cfg files?

When googling, the different commands like mailx or sendmail have very complicated parameters and many that i dont require like ssl etc.

Comment: I cannot imagine anything simpler than mailx or sendmail, see for example https://superuser.com/a/219051/297028

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to sending email from ***within*** the database, you can

- set database parameter "smtp_out_server" to "XXX.XXX.XXX.66:25"
- then use the UTL_MAIL package to send emails

That is probably the quickest and easiest way to send simple emails.